# React Native error the component must be a react component

Tags: ios, react-native, components, react-navigation

So i am new to react native and JS in general, i have a huge background in native mobile development and i want to know more about Web Apps. So i try to begin with react native to experience that.

I wanted to do a side menu using createDrawerNavigator, so i created the following component :

```
// code for the menu
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer, DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";


import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const App = createDrawerNavigator({
    HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    LinksScreen: {
        screen: LinksScreen
    },
    SettingsScreen: {
        screen: SettingsScreen
    }
    }, 
    {
      drawerWidth: 300
});

export default createAppContainer(App);

// HomeScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Dimensions,  
} from 'react-native';
import { WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer, DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";
import Router from './MenuNavigator';
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
header: 'Vapeself 2',
  };

  render() {
const App = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
        screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});
const MyApp = createAppContainer(App);
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());

    return (
        <Router/>
        );

  }

// LinkScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ExpoLinksView } from '@expo/samples';

export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Links',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {/* Go ahead and delete ExpoLinksView and replace it with your
           * content, we just wanted to provide you with some helpful links */}
        <ExpoLinksView />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },

});
// SettingsScreen.js

import React from 'react';
import { ExpoConfigView } from '@expo/samples';

export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'app.json',
  };

  render() {
    /* Go ahead and delete ExpoConfigView and replace it with your
     * content, we just wanted to give you a quick view of your config */
    return <ExpoConfigView />;
  }
}
```

I don't know what happened because the code doesn't work, and i have this kind of error **The component for route 'HomeScreen' must be a React component** . But the thing is that its actually work with a TabNavigator. So i really don't understand.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I dont see anywhere that you have imported MyHomeScreen

Comment: yes i see what do you mean, i'll check tomorow and i'll tell, thank you !

Comment: so i remove this part and still the same problem ( MyHomeScreen + MyNotificationsScreen part)